# Copying multiple table data with relations using EF core

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I have seven tables that contain hundreds of rows of related data. These tables build up quite a complex quoting tool that adds materials and costs etc.

Is it possible using EF Core and a couple of lines of code to load up all those entities, and then write them back as new ones but generating new ID's on the way and correctly relating everything to each other so I end up with complete copies of all the data. I can then change the CompanyID on the Header table and voila, a company has a complete copy of templates that they can now configure themselves.

I am about to write a procedure to load up entities one by one, loop over them, save rows one by one etc, store the id's, blah blah blah. I'm happy to write that procedure because I cannot see an automatic way to do it.

Comment: Are those primary keys that you want to update? Because entity framework does not support changing the primary key. Also the issue is that you want something that will simply update the columns and not iterate through the rows or that you simply want to use C# code and not a procedure?

Comment: Yep I am updating primary keys and am hoping EF Core will just do all the grunt work and update all the child entities in memory and write it all back as new rows like magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I can think of to do it with EF Core. Since it does not support tampering with the primary keys you could try something like this if you dont want to create a procedure but I can see a way to perform cascade update on primary keys. This kind of code would allow you to change the primary keys using custom ids based on your needs. You will still need for loops. So yeah you first update the primary table and the below it the tables that are depending on it.

```
foreach(var row in your_entity){
  your_context.your_new_entity.AddObject(row);
  your_context.SaveChanges();
  row.Id = your_id;
  for(var row2 in your_depending_entity){
    row2.foreignkey = your_id
    .... // and so on 
  }
}
```